# blender 2.8 select vertex, edge, face problem

Tags: interface, shortcut

i work on a macbook pro (no numpad) with  Blender 2.8 (no ctrl+tab shortcut) and i only have the choice to select between emulate numpad to chage point of view or not emulate numpad and use ctrl+1,2 or 3 to choose between vertex, edge or face modes.

it's not possible to have both? i tried to bind vertex, edge and face select modes to a quick favorites but its not possible

Any idea or solution?

Comment: Can you not work with the Fn-key?